# bootstrap class not working with select

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on ruby on rails application and trying to reduce size of select. I have 'bootstrap gem' installed for my application.
Here is the code

```
 <%= f.select :fromyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a.reverse, 
     :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"}, :class=>"input-small" %>
```

as I noticed class values from this question [Change width of select tag in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066528/change-width-of-select-tag-in-twitter-bootstrap). But seems like it is not working with this select. I have tried

```
<%= f.select :fromyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a.reverse, 
    :include_blank => {:year => "Select year"}, :style=>"100px" %>
```

but nothing happened.
Plz let me know what i am missing. Thanks

Comment: please tell you use `simple_form` or built-in `form_for`?

Comment: @Monk_Code i am using `form_for`

Comment: I am using form_for on other page. It is working fine on that view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.select(:fromyear, options_for_select((1995..Time.now.year).to_a.reverse), {:include_blank => 'Select year'}, { :class => 'input-small' }) %>
```

Or you can even include inline style inside a select tag with

```
<%= f.select(:fromyear, options_for_select((1995..Time.now.year).to_a.reverse), {:include_blank => 'Select year'}, { :class => 'input-small', :style => 'width:200px;', required: true }) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the syntax for `f.select` (in `form_for`):

`f.select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`

Right now you are passing `include_blank` and `class` as `options` parameter which is why the `class` is not applied. `class` must go in`html_options`.

All you need to do is **separate out** `options` and `html_options`.:

```
 <%= f.select :fromyear, (1995..Time.now.year).to_a.reverse, 
     {:include_blank => {:year => "Select year"}}, :class=>"input-small" %>
     ^                                          ^ 
   ## Added a curly bracket to separate out `include_blank` option and `class` option.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget to input the 'width' in the option :style ?

```
:style=>"width:100px"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way?

```
= a.input :country, :as => :select, :collection => country_code_localized_map, :include_blank => false, :input_html=>{:class => "reg-input"}
```

Or else you can add another `%DIV.select_above_class` above the select tag and apply styles via above class to select tag

```
.select_above_class select{
   // your css styles
}
```